# Sending POST using cpprest

Tags: c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have the following code to send POST, but I am getting an error with that even it compile correctly

```
http_client client(U("http://l0.71.103.63:34568"));
json::value postData;
postData["name"] = json::value::string(U("Mohammad"));

http_response response = client.request(methods::POST,postData.to_string().c_str()).get();

if(response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
{
  auto body = response.extract_string();
  std::wcout << L"Added new Id: " << body.get().c_str() << std::endl;

  return std::stoi(body.get().c_str());
}
```

But I am getting the following error when try to run the program

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'web::uri_exception'
what():  provided uri is invalid: {"name":"Mohammad"}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: The [number of overloads](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client.html) of `client::request` is bewildering, but at a guess, you need to pass a path before the json data. What did you pass to the `http_client` when you created it? perhaps you need to split the path out of that, just leaving the host name and pass the path to `client::request`?

Comment: @PaulRooney I created the client as following:
http_client client(U("http://l0.71.103.63:34568"));

Comment: What is the resource you are trying to post to? Can you do it with curl or with any other languages (e.g. Python requests)?  You could try a resource of `"/"` but that seems weird.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is your IP address. It looks like your IP address is wrong? You have "http://l0." where the "**1**0" is "**l**0" (lowercase L).

Hence the web:uri_exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong (I do think) in your request, should look like that:

> auto response = client.request(methods::POST, U("\"), postData).get();

The second argument in the request is the URL complement, and you are passing your json in string, hence the error you have. 
basically the syntax you want is this [one](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client.html#abbdc23648483780a7cc898bbdd306211):

> pplx::task web::http::client::http_client::request     (
>     const method &      mtd,        const utility::string_t & 
>     path_query_fragment,        const json::value &     body_data,      const
>   pplx::cancellation_token &    token = pplx::cancellation_token::none() 
>     )